# Unity C# : custom Object is null BUT I can access its properties

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I found a way to get around this issue in the code, but I would like to understand why this is happening because I want to learn C# well. I´ve searched a lot and could simplify the problem, here's the simplified code:

```
/*MyCustomComponent.cs, this is attached to a game object in the scene*/
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MyCustomComponent : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () {
        Test testInstance = new Test();
        Debug.Log (testInstance);
        Debug.Log (testInstance == null);
        Debug.Log (testInstance.Equals(null)); //Also tried the same with Equals()
        Debug.Log (testInstance.value);
    }
}

/*Test.cs*/
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Test : Object {
    public int value = 7;
    public Test(){

    }
}
```

Console Output:

```
null
true
7
```

Why is this happening? How can be possible an Object is null but returns a property value?

Comment: The output returns: null, true, true, 7. (I had the Equals() line commented out, so when I wrote it here I forgot to write the second true value).

Comment: You inherit your class from `Object`, your variable object is null, but class parameters exist. Remove `Object` from inheritance

Comment: In this context, it's important to note that `UnityEngine.Object` is not `System.Object`. The latter is the ultimate ancestor of all classes in C# , the former has its own behavior.

Comment: @MarkBenovsky I think that should be an answer...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer (that worked!). If I remove the ": Object" from Test.cs, it returns: Test (or false if the condition tries to see if it´s null).
Anyway, I still don´t get why when I do
testInstance = new UnityEngine.Object(); // or: new System.Object();
It returns null instead of Object. (it also returns true when the condition ask if its equal to null)

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I asked a question here. Do I need to do something to mark your comment as a correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Unity.Object` works in a very peculiar way, basically it contains data regarding the **managed** object while pointing to the **native** object (crudely speaking).

Let's make an example: you create a new object inheriting from `MonoBehaviour`. Now you have two objects, one on the native side and one on the managed side. You can access the `instanceID` propriety of the managed object thanks to the fact that `MonoBehaviour` inherits from `Unity.Object`. Basically, the latter is used to show all the relative data of the object in the Inspector.

Now, you want to `Destroy` this game object by calling the same named method. The native object is actually destroyed, but the managed object is not, since all managed objects can only be destroyed by the garbage collector. It's at this point that `Unity.Object` becomes `null`: it's a trick of the Unity engine uses in order to avoid that you try to access a native object which doesn't exist anymore. Eventually, when the GC is called, this `Unity.Object` will be destroyed too.

And this is why you should never create an Unity object which inherits directly from `Unity.Object`, but only from `MonoBehaviour` or `ScriptableObject`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I read all the replies again and also the UnityEngine.Object() and System.Object() documentation, and it's clear now. =)
My mistake was that I was trying to inherit from System.Object but I was using "Object" (which is UnityEngine.Object).